# Bumblebee with nvidia-331-updates. Work with "--driver nvidia" but won't work as service

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, bumblebee

I trying to set up bumblebee on ubuntu 12.04. I also using last nvidia driver because 319 isn't available any more.

This is my configuration files:

**/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf:**

```
    # Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia 
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-331-updates
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

**/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia:**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting may be needed in some platforms with more than one
#   nvidia card, which may confuse the proprietary driver (e.g.,
#   trying to take ownership of the wrong device). Also needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
#   BusID "PCI:01:00:0"

#   Setting ProbeAllGpus to false prevents the new proprietary driver
#   instance spawned to try to control the integrated graphics card,
#   which is already being managed outside bumblebee.
#   This option doesn't hurt and it is required on platforms running
#   more than one nvidia graphics card with the proprietary driver.
#   (E.g. Macbook Pro pre-2010 with nVidia 9400M + 9600M GT).
#   If this option is not set, the new Xorg may blacken the screen and
#   render it unusable (unless you have some way to run killall Xorg).
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"

    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

Then I show you couple mystical things:

First command:

```
    $ sudo /usr/sbin/bumblebeed -vv
[ 4828.053052] [DEBUG]Found card: 01:00.0 (discrete)
[ 4828.053093] [DEBUG]Found card: 00:02.0 (integrated)
[ 4828.053103] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 4828.053656] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia 
[ 4828.053678] [DEBUG]Skipping auto-detection, using configured driver 'nvidia '
[ 4828.053743] [DEBUG]bbswitch has been detected.
[ 4828.053753] [INFO]Switching method 'bbswitch' is available and will be used.
[ 4828.053762] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 4828.053770] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 4828.053778] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 4828.053786] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
[ 4828.053794] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 4828.053802] [DEBUG] pidfile: /var/run/bumblebeed.pid
[ 4828.053810] [DEBUG] xorg.conf file: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.DRIVER
[ 4828.053818] [DEBUG] xorg.conf.d dir: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
[ 4828.053826] [DEBUG] ModulePath: 
[ 4828.053833] [DEBUG] GID name: bumblebee
[ 4828.053841] [DEBUG] Power method: auto
[ 4828.053849] [DEBUG] Stop X on exit: 1
[ 4828.053857] [DEBUG] Driver: nvidia 
[ 4828.053865] [DEBUG] Driver module: nvidia 
[ 4828.053872] [DEBUG] Card shutdown state: 1
[ 4828.054045] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 3031.
[ 4828.054143] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe
[ 4828.056711] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[ 4828.056777] [ERROR]Module 'nvidia ' is not found.
```

Second command:

```
    $ sudo /usr/sbin/bumblebeed -vv --driver nvidia
[ 4742.214895] [DEBUG]Found card: 01:00.0 (discrete)
[ 4742.214970] [DEBUG]Found card: 00:02.0 (integrated)
[ 4742.215000] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 4742.215609] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia 
[ 4742.215660] [DEBUG]Skipping auto-detection, using configured driver 'nvidia'
[ 4742.215885] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 3023.
[ 4742.215981] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe
[ 4742.218520] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[ 4742.218667] [DEBUG]bbswitch has been detected.
[ 4742.218730] [INFO]Switching method 'bbswitch' is available and will be used.
[ 4742.218769] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 4742.218805] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 4742.218834] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 4742.218871] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates
[ 4742.218908] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 4742.218949] [DEBUG] pidfile: /var/run/bumblebeed.pid
[ 4742.218981] [DEBUG] xorg.conf file: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
[ 4742.219010] [DEBUG] xorg.conf.d dir: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
[ 4742.219040] [DEBUG] ModulePath: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
[ 4742.219074] [DEBUG] GID name: bumblebee
[ 4742.219102] [DEBUG] Power method: auto
[ 4742.219136] [DEBUG] Stop X on exit: 1
[ 4742.219172] [DEBUG] Driver: nvidia
[ 4742.219202] [DEBUG] Driver module: nvidia-331-updates
[ 4742.219238] [DEBUG] Card shutdown state: 1
[ 4742.219431] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 3024.
[ 4742.219517] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe
[ 4742.221990] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
[ 4742.222054] [DEBUG]Configuration test passed.
[ 4742.222937] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
[ 4742.223214] [INFO]Switching dedicated card OFF [bbswitch]
[ 4742.404703] [INFO]Initialization completed - now handling client requests
```

And it's work!

I can't understand why first command isn't workable. In bumblebee.conf "driver" value is "nvidia". Why in first command it trying load driver module "nvidia" instead "nvidia-331-updates"? Both command must be workable or not. Together. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

change 
`LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates` to 
`LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current`

change `[driver-nvidia]` to

`Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]`

change `[driver-nouveau]` to

`Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]`

change `KernelDriver=nvidia-331-updates` to `KernelDriver=nvidia_331_updates` or `KernelDriver=nvidia`

THAT LOGIC BUMBLEBEE -.-

**UPDATE**
Try this:
change `LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates,/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates` to
`LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates,/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates`

My Bumblebee Config:

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia_331_updates
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates,/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

My xorg.conf.nvidia:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option         "AutoAddGPU" "false"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Device"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting may be needed in some platforms with more than one
#   nvidia card, which may confuse the proprietary driver (e.g.,
#   trying to take ownership of the wrong device). Also needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
#   Setting ProbeAllGpus to false prevents the new proprietary driver
#   instance spawned to try to control the integrated graphics card,
#   which is already being managed outside bumblebee.
#   This option doesn't hurt and it is required on platforms running
#   more than one nvidia graphics card with the proprietary driver.
#   (E.g. Macbook Pro pre-2010 with nVidia 9400M + 9600M GT).
#   If this option is not set, the new Xorg may blacken the screen and
#   render it unusable (unless you have some way to run killall Xorg).
    Identifier     "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "ProbeAllGpus" "false"
    Option         "NoLogo" "true"
    Option         "UseEDID" "false"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
    BusID          "PCI:01:00:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 540M"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Default Screen"
    Device         "DiscreteNvidia"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Virtual     1600 900
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

After fresh installation of Bumblebee and Nvidia and DKMS etc..

1. Create backup (if exist file) `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak`
2. Type `optirun -b none nvidia-settings -c :8` and save config xorg to `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`
3. `nvidia-settings` not saving to `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`. Configuration from 
   `nvidia-settings` has been saved to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

   You must move this file to bumblebee xorg-nvidia configuration. Type `sudo rm /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia && sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`
4. Reboot ;)

**It works for me**